# La funcion me muestra valor undefined al mostrar el IMC

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

necesito ayuda con la siguiente función. Lo que se trata es de...Debe realizar un programa que calcule el índice de masa corporal de 3 personas. De cada persona se deberán guardar los datos en un objeto. Y al final debe mostrar en pantalla los datos de las 3 personas e indicar cual de ellas tiene el mayor índice, el menor índice y en qué categoría se encuentra cada una según su índice. Pero para mostrar el IMC y la categoría me devuelve el valor undefined.

```
function cWeight(){
        if(weight.value!="" && size.value!=""){
        index = weight.value / (size.value* size.value);

        if(index<18.5){ category.innerHTML = 'Bajo Peso'; }
        else if(index>=18.5 && index<=24.9){ category.innerHTML = 'Peso normal'; }
        else if(index>=25 && index<=29.9){ category.innerHTML = 'Preobeso'; }
        else if(index>30){ category.innerHTML = 'Obesidad'; }

    }else{
        alert('Debe ingresar algunos datos.');
    }
    }
```

Este el la otra parte del codigo

```
 function indexWeight(){
        function Person(name,sname,yBorn,weight,size,index,category){
            this.name = name;
            this.sname = sname;
            this.yBorn = yBorn;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.size = size;
            this.index = index;
            this.category = category;
        }

        var name = document.getElementById('name').value,
        sname = document.getElementById('sname').value,
        yBorn = document.getElementById('yborn').value,
        weight = document.getElementById('weight').value,
        size = document.getElementById('size').value,
        index = index,
        category = category;

        newUser = new Person(name,sname,yBorn,weight,size,index,category);
        addNewPerson();
        cWeight();
    };

    var userData = [];
    function addNewPerson(){
        userData.push(newUser);
        document.getElementById('tabla').innerHTML += '<tbody><td>' + 
            newUser.name + '</td><td>' + 
            newUser.sname + '</td><td>' + 
            newUser.yBorn + '</td><td>' + 
            newUser.weight + '</td><td>' + 
            newUser.size + '</td></tbody>';
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vale, como comenta @abrancorrea, pareces tener un problema de scope de las variables, te recomiendo leer este articulo en el que detallan bastante bien sobre lo que trata el tema: https://yeisondaza.com/entendiendo-scopes-de-variables-en-javascript

Otra cosa, al declarar variables, debes utilizar las palabras clave **var**, **let** o **const**. te recomiendo usar **let** para variables y **const** para constantes, esta imagen explica muy bien por qué:

[image: Tabla const let var]

Una ultima cosita, y es que a la hora de definir una función, debes plantearte siempre "¿Que necesita esta función para ejecutarse?", todas estas cosas que necesite, deberías pasarlas como **parametros**, estos se pasan entre los paréntesis que tiene la función, separados por comas. Te dejo la referencia de MDN en español para que le eches un ojo:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones

Explicado esto, vamos al lio con el código ;)

> Realizar un programa que calcule el índice de masa corporal de 3 personas. De cada persona se deberán guardar los datos en un objeto. Y al final debe mostrar en pantalla los datos de las 3 personas e indicar cual de ellas tiene el mayor índice, el menor índice y en qué categoría se encuentra cada una según su índice.

Crearemos una clase "Person" con los atributos correspondientes, luego definiremos las funciones indexWeight, cWeight y addNewPerson.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name,sname,yBorn,weight,size){
   this.name = name;
   this.sname = sname;
   this.yBorn = yBorn;
   this.weight = weight;
   this.size = size;
   /* las propiedades index y category seran propias del objeto, es decir, se calcularan al crearlo */
   this.index = this.weight / (this.size ** 2);
  }
  
  /* para category, utilizaremos un getter, es decir, que la propiedad se calculará cuando se solicite 
  * esto reemplaza al metodo cWeight
  */
  
  get category() {
    if(this.index<18.5){ return 'Bajo Peso'; }
    else if(this.index>=18.5 && index<=24.9){ return 'Peso normal'; }
    else if(this.index>=25 && index<=29.9){ return 'Preobeso'; }
    else if(this.index>30){ return 'Obesidad'; }
  }
}

// ahora crearemos una funcion que, cada vez que se llame, cree una nueva persona y la agregue a una tabla

function indexWeight() {
  const name = document.getElementById('name').value,
  const sname = document.getElementById('sname').value,
  const yBorn = document.getElementById('yborn').value,
  const weight = document.getElementById('weight').value,
  const size = document.getElementById('size').value,

  const newUser = new Person(name,sname,yBorn,weight,size);
  
  addNewPerson(newUser);
}

function addNewPerson(newUser) {
  document.getElementById('tabla').innerHTML += '<tbody><td>' + 
    newUser.name + '</td><td>' + 
    newUser.sname + '</td><td>' + 
    newUser.yBorn + '</td><td>' + 
    newUser.weight + '</td><td>' + 
    newUser.size + '</td><td>' +
    newUser.index + '</td><td>' +
    newUser.category + '</td></tbody>';
}
```

Otra cosita, usando template literals te ahorras tener que estar concatenando strings todo el rato! te dejo la referencia en MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings

Recuerda que debes llamar a newUser.category para que se ejecute el metodo, un abrazo y espero poder haberte ayudado ;)

Answer (score 1):

La función te devuelve el valor `undefined` porque en ella la variable `index` no está declarada. Si dentro de una función vas a usar un valor que esta fuera de su alcance debes pasarla como argumento.

`cWeight(index)`

y la función debe recibirla

`function cWeight (index){...}`

Recuerda que las variables creadas con var no crean un alcance con los bloques de código `{}` a excepción de si estos pertenecen a una función. Y también que se recomienda el uso de `const` y `let` en lugar de `var` para declarar variables, así como de la creación de clases nativas.